# CSS text transition only works when HTML input has "required" tag

Tags: html, css, forms, text, transition

I have text input fields in a form that I styled so that the labels start in the boxes, then slide up when a field is in focus. However, this only works for the "required" fields, and all of the other ones have the labels already above the boxes. How do I make those ones behave like the rest?

[Picture of the form fields in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul41v.png)

HTML:

```
        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" required>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="company">Company</label>
        </div>

        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="url" maxlength="80" name="url" size="20" type="text">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="url">Website</label>
        </div>

        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="city">City</label>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tGroup { 
    position:relative; 
    margin-bottom:45px; 
    float:left;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.tGroup input {
    font-size:.9em;
    padding:10px 0px;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    border:none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}

.tGroup input:focus { outline:none; }

.tGroup label {
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight:normal;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    top:10px;
    transition:0.2s ease all; 
    -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
    -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
  
/* active state */
.tGroup input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label {
    top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a Code Snippet? If you don't know how to, that's perfectly fine! Check out this link to find out how: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `input:valid ~ label` because you are saying that you want the inputs that are valid to have applied that specific style on the label, but since the last 2 don't have a required attribute they don't classify. You can just remove that.

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.tGroup { 
    position:relative; 
    margin-bottom:45px; 
    float:left;
    margin-right: 40px;
     margin-top: 30px;
}

.tGroup input {
    font-size:.9em;
    padding:10px 0px;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    border:none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}

.tGroup input:focus { outline:none; }

.tGroup label {
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight:normal;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    top:10px;
    transition:0.2s ease all; 
    -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
    -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
  
/* active state */
.tGroup input:focus ~ label  {
    top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" required>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="company">Company</label>
        </div>

        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="url" maxlength="40" name="url" size="20" type="text">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="url">Website</label>
        </div>

        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label for="city">City</label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do see one little issue when running the snipet. After entering the information in the input text and losing focus the text label comes back down overlapping with the information entered.

Here is an alternative solution using a bit of JavaScript.

I just duplicated the class you had implemented for the initial style of the labels and in the duplicate I just changed the position absolute to bottom.

Then with JS I looped over the inputs adding focusin event listeners using the event(e) object for the targeting and then when each input is clicked I just modified the class.

In the HTML I added the .startLabel class for the initial style. Also, I put the label right next to the inputs (Without spaces nor carriage return) for better targetting of the next sibling in the DOM.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (let input of inputs) {
    input.addEventListener('focusin', function(e){
        addClass(e);
    }, false);
}





function getTarget(e){
    return e.target;
}

function addClass(e){
    let target; 
    let label;
    target = getTarget(e);
    label = target.nextSibling;
    label.className = 'lableup';
}
```

```css
body    {
    background-color: black;
}

.tGroup { 
    position: relative; 
    margin-bottom: 45px; 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.tGroup input {
    font-size:.9em;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

.tGroup input:focus { outline:none; }

.startLabel {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease all; 
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.lableup {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 40px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: normal;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease all; 
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

  

.tGroup input: focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label {
    top:-20px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required><label for="email" class="startLabel">Email</label><span class="bar"></span>

        </div>

        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" required><label for="company" class="startLabel">Company</label>
            <span class="bar"></span>

        </div>

        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="url" maxlength="80" name="url" size="20" type="text"><label for="url" class="startLabel">Website</label>
            <span class="bar"></span>

        </div>

        <div class="tGroup">
            <input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text"><label for="city" class="startLabel">City</label>
            <span class="bar"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```